# C++ Error C2280: Attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ project for which one feature is to take an algebraic expression in infix notation, convert it to post-fix notation, and solve it. The conversion to post-fix works properly, and I believe my code for evaluating the post-fix expression will work as intended, but I am unable to compile due to error C2280. Here is the code for the post-fix evaluation (I am very new to C++ so anyone experienced with it may have an aneurysm when they see how poor this probably is):

```
string EvaluatePostfix(string expression) {
    double num;
    double leftOp;
    double rightOp;
    string leftOpString;
    string rightOpString;
    stringstream numberToPush;
    double tempResult;
    string tempResultString;
    stringstream tempResultSS;
    stack<stringstream> S;
    string finalResultString;


    for (std::size_t i = 0, l = expression.size(); i < l; ++i) { 
        if (expression[i] == '=')
            break;
        else if (isalnum(expression[i])) { //If the first character is alphanumeric, get ready to push to stack. 
            while (expression[i] != ' ') { //Wait until hitting space to ensure entire number is pushed, not just 1 digit
                numberToPush << expression[i];
                i++;
            }
            S.push(numberToPush);

        }

        else if (IsOperator(expression[i])) { //When an operator is hit, top two strings are taken from stack and converted to double.
            switch (expression[i]) {          //Operation is applied, they are converted back to string and result is pushed onto stack
            case '+':
                leftOpString == S.top().str();
                S.pop();
                rightOpString == S.top().str();
                S.pop();
                leftOp = atof(leftOpString.c_str());
                rightOp = atof(rightOpString.c_str());
                tempResult = leftOp + rightOp;
                tempResultString = to_string(tempResult);
                for (int i = 0; i < tempResultString.length() - 1; i++) {
                    tempResultSS << tempResultString.at(i);
                }
                S.push(tempResultSS);   
                break;
            case '-':
                leftOpString == S.top().str();
                S.pop();
                rightOpString == S.top().str();
                S.pop();
                leftOp = atof(leftOpString.c_str());
                rightOp = atof(rightOpString.c_str());
                tempResult = leftOp - rightOp;
                tempResultString = to_string(tempResult);
                for (int i = 0; i < tempResultString.length() - 1; i++) {
                    tempResultSS << tempResultString.at(i);
                }
                S.push(tempResultSS);
                break;
            case '*':
                leftOpString == S.top().str();
                S.pop();
                rightOpString == S.top().str();
                S.pop();
                leftOp = atof(leftOpString.c_str());
                rightOp = atof(rightOpString.c_str());
                tempResult = leftOp * rightOp;
                tempResultString = to_string(tempResult);
                for (int i = 0; i < tempResultString.length() - 1; i++) {
                    tempResultSS << tempResultString.at(i);
                }
                S.push(tempResultSS);
                break;
            case '/':
                leftOpString == S.top().str();
                S.pop();
                rightOpString == S.top().str();
                S.pop();
                leftOp = atof(leftOpString.c_str());
                rightOp = atof(rightOpString.c_str());
                tempResult = leftOp / rightOp;
                tempResultString = to_string(tempResult);
                for (int i = 0; i < tempResultString.length() - 1; i++) {
                    tempResultSS << tempResultString.at(i);
                }
                S.push(tempResultSS);
                break;
            case '^':
                leftOpString == S.top().str();
                S.pop();
                rightOpString == S.top().str();
                S.pop();
                leftOp = atof(leftOpString.c_str());
                rightOp = atof(rightOpString.c_str());
                tempResult = pow(leftOp, rightOp);
                tempResultString = to_string(tempResult);
                for (int i = 0; i < tempResultString.length() - 1; i++) {
                    tempResultSS << tempResultString.at(i);
                }
                S.push(tempResultSS);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    finalResultString == S.top().str();
    return finalResultString;

}
```

Here is the entire error message:

```
Error   C2280   'std::basic_stringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function  ConsoleApplication2 c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0 737
```

And here are lines 733-738, which contain the line where it says the error lies:

```
template<class _Objty,
    class... _Types>
    void construct(_Objty *_Ptr, _Types&&... _Args)
    {   // construct _Objty(_Types...) at _Ptr
    ::new ((void *)_Ptr) _Objty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction towards fixing this.

Comment: Which line in *your* code does it stop on?  Look at the call stack and see which line of your program is eventually calling this function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Isn't this a compiler error?

Comment: Still, the error messages at some point will show the line of code that eventually calls that function.

Comment: Your `while` loop is pushing the same `stringstream` onto the stack over and over. You're not creating a different stream for each expression that you write to the stream.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, will try to fix that now!

Comment: I think the error may be from trying to push a `stringstream` onto the stack. This error happens if you try to copy an object that's not copyable.

Comment: See the **Related** questions for similar issues.

Comment: @Barmar is that as simple as clearing the numberToPush string stream after it's pushed onto the stack? Or do I need to declare separate stringstream variables for each number that I will be pushing to the stack? I tried the former by changing the while loop to have numberToPush.clear() after the loop is exited but got the same error.            Edit: Just saw your other comment. I will try to use something other than stringstream. Thanks for the help : - )

Comment: @Barmar trying to push stringstreams onto a stack was the problem. For some reason I ran into problems earlier trying to push a string onto a stack of strings, so I tried using stringstream instead. It is working now though. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comments made by Barman and answer given by HairyDuck, in accordance with stringstream reference

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

which states that copy operator is deleted
copy (3)
stringstream (const stringstream&) = delete;

and assuming stack is std::stack which specifies that push

"Inserts a new element at the top of the stack, above its current top element. The content of this new element is initialized to a copy of val."
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/push/

=> Do not use a stack::push with a non copyable type.